# Sublime Text 2 how to select from line N to line M

Tags: sublimetext2

When I view log, I want to delete some useless lines, so I need this function. Anyone knows? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about something similar but with much richer functionality, but had no time recently to code it. So I wrote this one for your problem and as a starter for my idea:

https://github.com/vlakarados/SublimeLineWorks

In ST open command palette (ctrl/cmd+shift+p), find `LineWorks: Delete` and press enter.

Enter the lines you want to delete as a range:

To delete lines from 3 to 5 simply input `3:5` and press enter.
See if it works in ST2, please, as I have it working under ST3.

Comment: test, not work,  console log :  TypeError: unbound method delete() must be called with Lineworks instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)

Comment: I will try to fix this as soon as I may get my hands on ST2